# app crashes: E/AndroidRuntime + android.support.v4.content.FileProvider class not found

Tags: react-native, crash, androidx, android-fileprovider, android-runtime

Recently, I've migrated to AndroidX because I couldn't run `react-native run-android` and it suggested me to add `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` to my `<application>` tag in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file. so after searching a lot I was somehow convinced to migrate to AndroidX. beside making some changes in AndoirdManifest file I added the 2 below lines to my *gradle.properties*:

`android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true`

... also I had to make some changes in 7 packages in node_modules to be compatible with androidx. and finally I could BUILD SUCCESSFUL, but now the problem is that my app crashes. and in logcat I have the err that 
`E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: ....` 
in some searches I found out that maybe making some changes in `<provider>` in AnroidManifest file would be the answer but the truth is that I don't have any provider tags in my AndroidManifest file. so there again I stuck and don't know how to solve this issue

**Extra info:** ((Packages that have been changed)):

```
`|__ lottie-react-native
 |__ react-native-firebase
 |__ react-native-gesture-handler
 |__ @cedarstudios
    `|__ react-native-mapbox-gl
 |__ react-native-maps
 |__ react-native-push-notifications
 |__ rn-fetch-blob
```

*What I've tried:*

I added provider then again new errors occur. then again I removed that

Part of my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<application
      tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
      android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:fullBackupContent="false"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:supportsRtl="false"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:largeHeap="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Part of the logcat error:

```
54565:06-23 16:00:09.544 22227 22227 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.myAppName, PID: 22227
54566:06-23 16:00:09.544 22227 22227 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.myAppName-YLgUAaSaaK5LGP1d0LJLSw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myAppName-YLgUAaSaaK5LGP1d0LJLSw==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.myAppName-YLgUAaSaaK5LGP1d0LJLSw==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib]]
54578:06-23 16:00:09.544 22227 22227 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.myAppName-YLgUAaSaaK5LGP1d0LJLSw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myAppName-YLgUAaSaaK5LGP1d0LJLSw==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.myAppName-YLgUAaSaaK5LGP1d0LJLSw==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib]]
```

what I expect is to run my app successfully on my phone without crashing

*PM* if you need to know more information about my issue in order to answer my question, ask me please.

Answer (score 2):

Click to AndroidManifest.xml look at the bottom of the files page you gonna see "Text" and "Merged Manifes" then click to "Merged Manifest" -> Search for "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" then change it with "androidx.core.content.FileProvider"

Thats it, exact solution.

Also change your android.support.v4 with androidx version libraries. Please search for new androidx versions of android libraris

Comment: This solutin worked for me life magic after 2 days for build crash on android.